# OZEKI NG GATEWAY not receiving SMS messages

Tags: mobile, sms, sms-gateway

I'm working on a project in which I'm trying to get Ozeki to send and receive SMS messages from my Nokia 3110 classic.I have also configured the inbound route,outbound route,GSM modem service provider and standard user correctly.Sending messages is working fine but not receiving them. Please give me some solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

Does your service provider definitely support inbound SMS from all other operators? SMS routing is notoriously tricky with many operators and gateway providers supporting only a selection of other providers.

Answer (score 0):

Nokia phones work best with SMSEnabler not with ozekiNG.please start using SMSEnabler instead which uses http api to send and receive SMS like ozeki.I was having the same problem you can't help it.